# Alternatives to using EXEC(@sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a good alternative to using `EXEC(@sql)` when you need to be able to change server and database references as shown in the example below?

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM '+@server+'.'+@database+'.dbo.mytable'
EXEC(@sql)
```

I have been using this approach for a while now but when queries become longer it becomes more complicated to validate the queries.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

All of our development is done in visual studio so the ideal solution would be a way to still be able to get the benefits of intelliSense  while the query remains dynamic.

Comment: If there are *good* reasons for there to be multiple databases (on multiple servers) with the same schema then no, there's not many better alternatives. Alternatively, it may be that all of this data could belong in a single database and the data embedded in server and database names ought instead to be plain data in additional columns. If such a transformation is valid, then of course you end up with straightforward queries after that.

Comment: use     EXEC SP_EXECUTE @sql

Comment: What's the issue? Even if the query becomes longer, the `EXEC` will still work fine as long as the query is correct. It's the only way if you are using dynamic queries

Comment: @koushikveldanda, since there does not seem to be an alternative that will allow me to utilize IntelliSense sp_executesql will help keep the queries clean and simple but can you set you server and database with parameters? I am having trouble getting it to accept this.